# TextField doesn't render when fullWidth is true

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a React application and I am using [Material react-text-field](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material/react-text-field). For some reason when I mark `fullWidth` as `true`, only the outline of the input field is shown. If I set `fullWidth` to `false`, everything works fine (except my input control is not full width).

Here is a screen shot of how it renders if `fullWidth` is `false`:

[image]

And here is a screen shot of how it renders if `fullWidth` is `true`:

[image]

Note that I cannot click in the text box anymore or type any text in the text box, nor is my label showing now.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField, { HelperText, Input } from '@material/react-text-field';

import './LoginBox.scss';

export default class LoginBox extends React.Component {
    state = { value: '' };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login-box">
                <div className="caption">
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    <p>Enter username or email address and password to log in.</p>
                    <hr />
                </div>
                <div className="content">
                    <TextField
                        outlined={true}
                        fullWidth={true}
                        label="Email or Username"
                    >
                        <Input
                            value={this.state.value}
                            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ value: e.currentTarget.value })}
                        />
                    </TextField>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain why changing this `fullWidth` property would cause this behavior to occur?

Answer (score -1):

Use `fluid` Instead of `fullWidth: true`

Solution:

```
 <TextField
   outlined={true}
   fluid
   label="Email or Username"
 >
```

Comment: This did not help. Same result as setting `fullWidth` to `false`. It does not extend to the end of the container, as shown in my first screen shot.

Comment: try with inline css: style={{ width: 100% }}